# How to install Matlab R2020a on Arch based distros

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, manjaro, matlab

I had a problem installing `Matlab R2020a` on my Manjaro so I decided to share my solution from A to B.

Comment: Questions are "solved" on SE by having accepted answers; no need for those words in the title.

Comment: Please also describe in your question the problems you encountered so that future visitors can find your Q&A based on those key words. Thank you!

Comment: sorry didnt know how to call it exactly
But the things I wrote here are basically things to do to avoid all of those errors

Comment: There is a large collection of hints in the Arch Wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MATLAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we download the installed (in `.zip` form) from the `mathworks.com` site), then we have to unzip it in a very exact way:

```bsh
$ unzip -X -K matlab_R2020a_glnxa64.zip
```

That will give us the `install` script.
We will run the Matlab installer using it but depending on the size of our installation (aka how many `toolboxes` we want to install) our installation may crash because Matlab will want to much space at once. Therefore either you have to specify a special folder for downloads (but I didn't get it to work so idk) or just like me simply install the most basic version of `Matlab` `without` any toolboxes and then install them afterwards.
So we just go:

```bsh
sudo ./install
```

And we install `Matlab` but without any toolboxes.

Matlab generally is buggy as hell and its probably that you will have to do the same as me. Even tho you could login to mathworks during the installation the exec at `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/matlab` may refuse to work because of license or something. In that case make sure to go:

```bsh
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/activate_matlab.sh
```

This script should let you enable your license. If there are any errors google them and the issue can probably be resolved on `mathworks` website, you will have to say that yes its your computer, combine your Host ID (google it) or something. But generally after that you should be good to go.

As you can see for me at least the basic version with Simulink works:

[image]
It is very important that you check if plots appear etc. Matlab is known for issues with drivers on Linux, it might happen that it will have some problems with java or other libs but for these are plenty of posts online.

This video can probably guide you on how to install those `toolboxes`, it's easy, just make sure to start `matlab` in superuser mode (`sudo`) or else it won't have needed permissions

If you also have any problems with license check this post(I wrote to MathWorks and they sent me this link, it worked for me with -9 error):

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99067-why-do-i-receive-license-manager-error-9